# appView.addJavascriptInterface() does not work on API 17

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

i am able to use java function from my phonegap java script function and android 2.2 
but same code is not run on API 17. what should i have to do to call native java code on from java script in API 17.

i use this code in my java file

```
 objCustomNativeAccess = new CustomNativeAccess(this, appView);
            appView.addJavascriptInterface(objCustomNativeAccess,
                    "CustomNativeAccess");
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

my CustomNativeAccess class is

```
public class CustomNativeAccess {
        private WebView mAppView;
        private DroidGap mGap;

        /**
         * Constructor
         * 
         * @param gap
         * @param view
         */
        public CustomNativeAccess(DroidGap gap, WebView view) {
            mAppView = view;
            mGap = gap;
        }

        /**
         * Get the device phone number
         * 
         * @return
         */
        public JSONObject login(String email, String password) {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                    object.put("Login_Status", login_status);
            object.put("date", dateString);
            return object;
        }
```

and in my java script i use this line to call this login function

```
 var value = window.CustomNativeAccess.login(email,pass);
```

so using this i successfully call this on api 2.2 but when i run this code on api 17 it give me error

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'login' at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:81

how i can i use this on api 17

Answer (score 39, accepted):

What you have to do on API 17 is annotate your method with `@JavascriptInterface`:

```
public class CustomNativeAccess {
   @JavascriptInterface
```

and then get rid of the constructor part:

```
/*private WebView mAppView;
    private DroidGap mGap;
    public CustomNativeAccess(DroidGap gap, WebView view) {
        mAppView = view;
        mGap = gap;
    }
*/
```

Also be sure you import JavascriptInterface in your project:

```
 import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
```

You can read about it more here:
[WebView Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29)

Edit: You will have to annotate each method with @JavascriptInterface within your class that you'd like to access from Javascript.

Comment: One can use constructors that is not a problem.

Comment: no probs with the constructors, but it's not necessary at that point and

Comment: I can confirm that there is no problem with the constructor. The conditions are methods must have the annotation **@JavascriptInterface** and be **public**.

Comment: should add `@SuppressLint( "AddJavascriptInterface")` and `@JavascriptInterface` in my case.

Comment: It is said that this is for security: "Any untrusted content hosted in a WebView could potentially use reflection to figure out the public methods within the JavascriptInterface object and could then make use of them." ( https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/02/security-enhancements-in-jelly-bean.html ) . This is only of the object that has it right? It can't reach further? If I have an anonymous class for it, and it has a single function (and it has this annotation), is it dangerous?

Answer (score 4):

From the Android 4.2 documentation:

> Caution: If you've set your targetSdkVersion to 17 or higher, you must
>   add the **@JavascriptInterface** annotation to any method that you want
>   available your web page code (**the method must also be public**). If you
>   do not provide the annotation, then the method will not accessible by
>   your web page when running on Android 4.2 or higher.

Source: Android WebView Doc (emphasis added)

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote the web application with `addJavascriptInterface` with API 17, it works well. I don't know what happened to your code. Maybe you can try these:

make sure you add the :

```
WebSettings webSettings = appView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Second, why do you use super.loadUrl, not appView to load the html?

```
objCustomNativeAccess = new CustomNativeAccess(this, appView);
appView.addJavascriptInterface(objCustomNativeAccess, "CustomNativeAccess");
appView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

Comment: `appView.setJavaScriptEnabled` does not exist , which `PhoneGap version` did you used?? i am using version `2.9`

Comment: sorry, there is a mistake. it should be `webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true).` And I never use PhoneGap.

Answer (score -1):

Solutions:

1. Lower the `android:targetSdkVersion` in the manifest file to 16.
2. Change the compilation api level to 17 in project.properties: `target=android-17` and annotate the callback method with `@JavascriptInterface`.

Comment: It's outdated answer. Play store will not allow to set targetsdk=17. FYI