# Chromium error has occurred in Android Version 4.3 and above Versions but not it 4.1.2?

Tags: javascript, android, chromium

I've successfully created a webview project and it's working well on 4.1.2 android version. When i run the same app on 4.3, 4.4 it's not working. I've come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353430/appview-addjavascriptinterface-doen-not-work-on-api-17) and [this too.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29)

My project had javascript call to invoke some functions in the android class files. One of the function i used it for displaying selected image on the corresponding date. The image has been added successfully but it doesn't displayed. I got an error in my console like this,

**12-18 17:34:13.089: I/chromium(17133): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Not allowed to load local resource: content://sconnie1_640x960.png"**

I've loaded my webview URL from web not in locally. The same error has been occured when i change it to load a URL form locally.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, i was misplaced the .html file in asset folder. Very silly mistake but it took more than a day to resolved. I feel very bad at myself. After declaring the correct path it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled content access for the webview?

```
webview.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true)
```

[WebSettings.setAllowContentAccess(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setAllowContentAccess%28boolean%29)

Comment: I didn't. But after adding this also getting the same error I/chromium(3868): [INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///". I hope this problem something around security issues on kitkat version. But i couldn't able to find it exactly.

Comment: The error message has changed, before it was content:// now it's file:// 

add also these lines:

webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); // only needed if you access files outside file:///android_asset and file:///android_res

webview.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

Comment: thanks for your reply. Sorry, it doesn't matter file or content, in-fact me only changed that path. The problem is loading file from local path into a webview and its not yet resolved it remains same even i added webview.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   ?