# JS to JAVA - appView.addJavascriptInterface() does not work in Phonegap 7

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova, phonegap

I'm trying to figure out why `appView.addJavascriptInterface()` does not work in my Phonegap project. I've tried [solution provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353430/appview-addjavascriptinterface-does-not-work-on-api-17) but no success.

My main goal is to pass the variable from Javascript to Java.

Error is: "`cannot find symbol method addJavascriptInterface(MainActivity,String)`"

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.myPhonegapProj;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.R;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.*;


public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity {

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // enable Cordova apps to be started in the background
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean("cdvStartInBackground", false)) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }

        appView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "MainActivity");

        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }
}
```

What is the right way to pass the variable from Javascript to Java in Phonegap 7?